# How to gracefully replace the directory tree under CWD of shell?

Tags: linux, shell, filesystems, fuse

I do the following experiment on ext4:

```
# shell 1:
mkdir test
cd test

# shell 2:
rmdir test

# shell 1:
cd .
cd ..
```

In shell 1 I get to the parent directory.

Now I want to emulate this behaviour in my FUSE filesystem, but without explicit call to `rmdir`.

My FUSE is provided by daemon that accepts external commands and switches directory layout on demand. If I return `ENOENT` in `getattr()` and `EBADF` in `readdir()` when the entry not found in actual directory tree, then `cd ..` in shell doesn't change the current **missing** working directory.

What concept should I support in my filesystem to make the shell understand that current directory is gone and be able to go back by `cd ..`?